# While passing arguments to a Perl script, it's not opening the file

Tags: excel, perl, csv, cmd

**This is script is used to compare two .csv files and write difference in results.xls**

my perl script(name:cmp.pl) is:

```
#!C:\Perl\bin

use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Utility;

my $Wb = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('results.xls');
my $s1 = $Wb->add_worksheet('res');

open(FILE1, "< ARGV[0]") || die "Cannot open $ARGV[0]\n";
open(FILE2, "< ARGV[1]") || die "Cannot open $ARGV[1]\n";

@file1 = < FILE1>;
@file2 = < FILE2>;

my $format  = $Wb->add_format();
my $format1 = $Wb->add_format();

$format->set_bg_color('red');
$format1->set_bg_color('yellow');

for $i (0 .. $#file1) {

  $line1 = $file1[$i];
  $line2 = $file2[$i];

  if (!($line1 eq $line2)) {

    @x = split(/\,/, $line1);
    @y = split(/\,/, $line2);

    for $j (0 .. $#x) {
      if ((($x[$j] != $y[$j]) || (!($x[$j] eq $y[$j])))) {
        $s1->write($i, $j, $y[$j], $format);
      }
      else {
        $s1->write($i, $j, $y[$j], $format1);
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    @x = split(/\,/, $line1);
    $s1->write_row($i, 0, \@x);
  }
}

$Wb->close();

close(FILE1);
close(FILE2);
```

---

I passed the arguments(files) in cmd promt like

`\perl>cmp.pl t1.csv t2.csv`:

output:its showing cannot open

Comment: Did you use the `python` tag just to show no indentation is needed in Perl?

Comment: You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program you write, and declare all your variables as close as possible to their first point of use. This is especially true when you are asking for help with your code, as without it you haven't taken even the most rudimentary steps to debug it yourself. I am also unsurprised that you couldn't see a problem with your code in the state it was. Indenting your code properly is vital as a way of representing and understanding the control flow, and therefore also as an aid to finding bugs in your program.

Comment: Please change your `open` calls to look like this: `open FILE1, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "Cannot open '$ARGV[0]': $!\n"` so that you can see *why* they fail.

Answer (score 1):

The code where you open the files and read them into arrays `@file1` and `@file2` should look like this

```
open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0] or die qq{Cannot open "$ARGV[0]": $!\n};
my @file1 = <$f1>;

open $fh, '<', $ARGV[1] or die qq{Cannot open "$ARGV[1]": $!\n};
my @file2 = <$f2>;

close $fh;
```

and the two `close` calls at the end should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your open lines - you've forgotten to put a `$` before the `ARGV[0]` (you're accessing an array element):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

You could use this:

```
open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0] or die $!;
```

Or this:

```
my $file = $ARGV[0];
open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
```

Comment: open my $file1, '<', $ARGV[0] or die $!;

open my $file2, '<', $ARGV[1] or die $!;

Its shows compilation error